# How to translate the Automated Logout module administration?

Tags: i18n-l10n

How to translate language of the [Automated Logout](https://www.drupal.org/project/autologout) module administration?

I was searching for translation of polish language and tired other modules.

Comment: Did you try to translate strings in Drupal admin interface "admin/config/regional/translate/translate"?

Comment: Yeah its good way to do it, but i think there's should be change in autologout-7.x-4.3.pl.po

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There IS a [Polish translation of the autologout module](https://localize.drupal.org/translate/projects/autologout) available. Though it is currently only translated for 42%.

The way I understand (translate???) your question is something like so: **How can I show the admin interface for the [Automated Logout](https://www.drupal.org/project/autologout) module in the Polish language?**

To answer that question, just swich to the Polish version of your site, and then use the admin link. As an alternative, enable the "language switcher block" so that it is shown within the theme you're using for Administration. Then navigate to anywhere within admin (whatever language), and use the language switcher block to show the admin interface in Polish (for about 42%). If you also want the remaining 58% to be shown translated, then it's up to you to actually add your custom translations of the various missing translations.

Comment: It looks like that was less than 42%. There's only 5 think's translated in autologout-7.x-4.3.pl.po, i know there's licences and I got no idea i could change it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that, want to retry?

Comment: Inside of this librarie, it's kind empty, or @msg not working.           :

msgid "user"
msgstr "użytkownik"
msgid "Enable"
msgstr "Włącz"
msgid "Yes"
msgstr "Tak"
msgid "No"
msgstr "Nie"
msgid "@msg"
msgstr "@msg"

Comment: Hm, accepted, merci (thank you)! So my "translation" of the translation issue was close (even correct)? Next question?